# set_yticks and ylim for categorical variables

Tags: python, matplotlib

(Matplotlib version 2.2.2)

I'm plotting some data where the values on the y-axis are discrete data.
What I would like to do is to set the range of categories of the y-axis to also include values that are not appearing in the data set.
Unfortunately I didn't find a way to add another category if it is not in the data.

Also, I want to set a specific order of categories, as they're currently placed in order of appearance.

Here is a MWE of what I currently have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
xs = list(range(10))
ys = ["on", "off", "off", "on","on", "off", "off", "on", "on", "off"]
ax1.plot(xs, ys)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
xs = list(range(10))
ys = ["on", "on", "on", "on","on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on"]
ax2.plot(xs, ys)

fig.show()
```

It produces the following output:
[image: MWE]

I also want to show "off" on the y-axis of the bottom plot.

---

**Current solution (not elegant, hoping for help):**

My quickfix solution so far: I add a line with the category names in the order I want them and x-coordinate values that are not in the visible area (I can easily do this with x-coordinates when they're numeric, because I can set the limit). 
I was however hoping that there is a more elegant solution (using the actual API or so).
This solution is also not possible when the x-axis is also discrete as it's not possible to set limits, afaik.

Quickfix source code (if somebody can use it):

```
...
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
xs = list(range(10))
ys = ["on", "on", "on", "on","on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on"]
ax2.set_xlim([0,(len(xs)-1)])
ax2.plot(xs, ys)
categories_in_order = ["on", "error", "off", "extra"]
ax2.plot([-100] * len(categories_in_order), categories_in_order)
...
```

produces: [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The categorical axes can still be limited using numeric values. Essentially each category is an integer number 0,1,2,..., N-1 on the axes. You may call `set_ylim`
like

```
ax2.set_ylim(-.05, 1.05)
```

or in this case it could also make sense to just copy the limits of the other axes,

```
ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
```

Even better, share the y axes between the subplots, e.g. using `sharey=True` in a call to subplots.

You may then also set the ticks to those categories you want

```
ax2.set_yticks(["off", "on"])
```

I do not currently know any way to produce "placeholders" for categories. So indeed, the order will be determined by the order of setting the data. But in this case an easy option is to invert the axis,

```
ax2.invert_yaxis()
```

In total:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharey=True) #

xs = list(range(10))
ys = ["on", "off", "off", "on","on", "off", "off", "on", "on", "off"]
ax1.plot(xs, ys)

xs = list(range(10))
ys = ["on", "on", "on", "on","on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on"]
ax2.plot(xs, ys)
ax2.set_yticks(["off", "on"])
ax2.invert_yaxis()


plt.show()
```

[image]